# Как удалить все числа из строк в массиве использую один цикл for? Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть такой код, где я пытаюсь удалить все числа из имен файлов. Все работает кроме собственно фактического изменения

```
   import os

   files_list = os.listdir('/mnt/c/Users/maverick/Desktop/prank/prank')
   for file_name in files_list:
       count = 0
       l = []
       for char in file_name:
           if not char.isdigit():
               l.append(char)
      new_string = ''.join(l)
      print('New string: ' + new_string)
      print('Old file name: ' + file_name)
      file_name = new_string
      print('New file name: ' + file_name)
      count = count + 1

  print(files_list)
```

Output:

```
  New string: oakland.jpg
  Old file name: 97oakland.jpg
  New file name: oakland.jpg  ......
  ['16los angeles.jpg', '17cairo.jpg', '22rochester.jpg', '28houston.jpg',.....]
```

Comment: Что значит "фактическое изменение"?

Answer (score 1):

Вы хотели, чтобы в `files_list` старые названия заменились на новые (без цифр)? `file_name = new_string` изменяет только переменную `file_name`, она не имеет отношения к изменению списка. Чтобы изменить первоначальный список `files_list` надо воспользоваться функцией `map` или создать новый список как показано ниже:

```py
import os

files_list = os.listdir('/mnt/c/Users/maverick/Desktop/prank/prank')
new_file_list = [''.join([c for c in name if not c.isdigit()]) for name in file_list]
# ['los angeles.jpg', 'cairo.jpg', 'rochester.jpg', 'houston.jpg']
```

Comment: Да. Я пытаюсь переименовать файлы, чтобы в названиях не было чисел.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте:

```
import os
import re

dir_name = '/mnt/c/Users/maverick/Desktop/prank/prank'

for file_name in os.listdir(dir_name):
    # Если в названии нет цифр пропускаем файл
    if not re.search('\d', file_name):
        continue

    # Удаляем из строки цифры
    new_file_name = re.sub('\d+', '', file_name)

    # Получаем полный путь к файлу
    abs_file_name = os.path.join(dir_name, file_name)
    abs_new_file_name = os.path.join(dir_name, new_file_name)

    # Переименовываем
    os.rename(abs_file_name, abs_new_file_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
''.join([i for i in file_name if not i.isdigit()])
```